# Bash script to compare pair of files line by line

Tags: bash

I have 20 pair of files( named as table0,table1..table10  and tabler0, tabler1.... tabler10 )  Now, I need to compare each pair of file line by line. Suppose table0 and tabler0 are files need to be compared then, first line of table0 is matched to all lines of tabler0. If matching line found then first line of table0 is replaced by 1 else by 0. 
e.g.

```
file1:
a
d
e
t
file2:
a
a
e
g
d
r
Output:
file1:
1
1
1
0
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way for accomplish this would be:

```
#reading file by line
while read line;do
   #check if file2 contains the line
   if grep -q $line "file2.txt"; then echo 1
   else echo 0
   fi
done < file1.txt
```

If you want to show the lines that file1 and file2 have in common,

```
#reading file by line
while read line;do
   #check if file2 contains the line
   if grep -q $line "file2.txt"; then echo $line
   fi
done < file1.txt
```